# I am facing System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.' while consuming API for posting XML data

Tags: c#, .net, api, console-application

I am setting up a c# console Application which deals with some API integration.I am facing System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.' Exception while consuming API which is POST method and Request Body is XML

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destinationUrl);
byte[] bytes =System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXml);
var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password");
request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic "+Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
request.Method = "POST";
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();
 HttpWebResponse   response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: What does your xml look like? Have you minified it to a single line?

Comment: have you tried removing single quotes around 'utf-8' ?

Comment: And i did not notice but you say ContentType is encoded in UTF-8 but you encode it in ASCII, try Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestXml)

Comment: My XML data is <request>< entry >< u_affected_user > Value </ u_affected_user >< u_caller_id > Value </ u_caller_id > < u_detail_description > TEST description </ u_detail_description >< u_impact > 2 </ u_impact >< u_urgency > 2 </ u_urgency >< u_incident_type > Value </ u_incident_type >< u_short_description > Value  </ u_short_description >< u_cmdb_ci > Value  </ u_cmdb_ci >< u_assignment_group > Value </ u_assignment_group > < u_source_system > Value  </ u_source_system ></ entry ></ request >

Comment: I have tried those I mean replace ASCII with utf-8 and content -type changed to 'application/xml' .Still its not working ..Since I am new to this I dont have much knowledge. Please help anyone..Thanks in advance